# How to reverse the order of a ListView Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Need help. I'm sorting a list with Firestore, but when I add data, it's always created at the bottom of `ListView.separated`. How to make the new data displayed not at the bottom, but at the top? As I understand it, you need to use the `reverse` command, but you could indicate exactly where and how correctly.

**firestore_repo**

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> getMainCollection() {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    return firestore.collection('notes').orderBy('date');
  }
```

**list_note**

```
child: ListView.separated(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(height: 5),
            itemCount: widget.snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> documentSnapshot =
                  widget.snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              return Dismissible(
                key: Key(documentSnapshot.id),
                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
final reveredList = widget.snapshot.data!.docs.reversed.toList();
```

Then use it in the `ListView` like so:

```
child: ListView.separated(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(height: 5),
            itemCount: reveredList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> documentSnapshot =
                 reveredList[index];
              return Dismissible(
                key: Key(documentSnapshot.id),
                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
```

Answer (score 2):

add this line to your `ListView.separated`:

```
 reverse: true,
```

so the code would be:

```
child: ListView.separated(
            reverse: true, 
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(height: 5),
            itemCount: widget.snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> documentSnapshot =
                  widget.snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              return Dismissible(
                key: Key(documentSnapshot.id),
                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
```

Comment: when I use reverse: true, then my first elements are shifted to the very bottom, and an indent remains at the top.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jqux.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In addition to reversing the data inside the UI/`ListView` as others have shown, you can also tell Firestore to return the data in reverse order. To do this, change your `orderBy` call to:

```
return firestore.collection('notes').orderBy('date', descending: true);
```